# Issue in running QR Code reader sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4, qr-code, i386, linker-errors

I am doing a project to read QR codes.For that I am using the sample code from 2D barcodes (QR Code, Data Matrix) - iOS4 or above only  from the link [http://www.quickmark.com.tw/En/basic/SDK.asp](http:////www.quickmark.com.tw/En/basic/SDK.asp) But when I am trying to run that sdk I am getting an error saying "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DecodePickerController", referenced from:Objc-class-ref in QMSampleViewController.o Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 Collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.
    what is the reason?anyone tried this?help please.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to build the sdk, there is no issue for device build.May be you are trying to build for iPhone simulator.
Please try to build it for device.